# Embed specific parts of external webpage

Tags: categories, menu, embed

So I am creating a website and want to embed a menu to it. We are currently using Leafly for our menu system and want to use it on the site too. However, there are 300+ products and I do not want to display one very long menu.

I would like to embed the categories of the menu separately so one page for flower, one for edibles, one for concentrates, etc etc.

Here is the leafly url [Leafly Menu](https://www.leafly.com/dispensary-info/new-vansterdam/menu)

and the div info for the categories

`<div class"m-accordion--main-group" data-ng-show="'Flower' == filterItem || filterItem == 'all'">`

So I would like to pull just the 'Flower' category onto the wordpress site but dont know how.

There is also an embed code:

`<script>var pymParent = pym.Parent('leafly-menu', location.protocol +
'//www.leafly.com/embed/menu2/new-vansterdam', {});</script>`

so maybe I can edit that protocol to just pull that category?

Comment: Can you clarify, how is this a WordPress specific  question? Because on [wordpress.se] only those are [on topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Template for a page and then in that template you make a WP_Query which only gets you posts with the 'Flower' Category.

This will look something like this:

```
// WP_Query arguments
 $args = array (
    'category_name'          => 'Flower',
);

// The Query
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
 wp_reset_postdata();
```